# Pass variable from controller to service angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
app.controller('ItemDetailsCtrl', function($scope,FavoriteService) {

var parameter = $scope.Diamoni.Favorites;
});


 app.service("FavoriteService",[function(){

  this.fav = 0; 
}]);
```

I would like to pass the variable parameter from ItemDetailsCtrl controller to FavoriteService, So this.fav=0; become this.fav=parameter Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this a +2 upvote? This already has a thousand answers.. Just google it before you ask such a simple question.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use $rootScope, instead use a function to set the params

In your service

```
var self = this;
this.setParam = function(param){
   self.fav = param
}
```

In your controller

```
  FavouriteService.setParam(parameter)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest way will be to expose your `fav` variable through get/set methods.

```
app.controller('ItemDetailsCtrl', function($scope, FavoriteService) {
    var parameter = $scope.Diamoni.Favorites;

    FavoriteService.setFav(parameter);
    console.log(FavoriteService.getFav()); // will be the proper value
});


app.service("FavoriteService",[function(){
    var fav = 0; 
    this.setFav = setFav;
    this.getFav = getFav;

    function setFav(favValue) {
        fav = favValue;
    }

    function getFav() { 
        return fav; 
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I'm confused why you define functions which would then be hoisted to global space as opposed to attaching them to `this`.  It *likely* works, but it's not consistent in my mind.

Comment: It is more for readability reasons than anything else. I'm used to work with relatively big services in some of my projects, so this way I can see the 'api' exposed by the service at a glance. I understand that defining them as anonymous functions and attaching them to `this` will not hoist the function definitions, but I'm really interested if you can elaborate on any problems, that can occur because of this syntax

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
app.controller('ItemDetailsCtrl', function($scope,FavoriteService) {
    var parameter = $scope.Diamoni.Favorites;
    FavoriteService.setParam(parameter);
});

app.service("FavoriteService",[function(){
    var service = this;
    service.setParam = function(parameter) {
        service.fav = parameter;
    };
}]);
```

I added a method to the service to set the `fav` variable.
its easy to  implement this kind of logic using factory instead of service. if you want i can send you  the factory code snippet

***EDIT***

using factory:

```
app.controller('ItemDetailsCtrl', function($scope,FavoriteService) {
    var parameter = $scope.Diamoni.Favorites;
    FavoriteService.setParam(parameter);
});


app.factory('FavoriteService', ['', function(){

    var service = {}

    service.setParam = function(parameter) {
        service.fav = parameter;
    };

    return service;
}])

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neat data sharing service example, where we store different data using `set` and `get` methods. Remember to store the values in an object or you can get some strange results sometimes.

Service:

```
graphs.service('graphsData', [function() {

  var graphs = this;

  var data = {
    all: null,
    list: null,
    single: null
  };

  graphs.set = function(k, v) {
    data[k] = v;
  };

  graphs.update = function(k, s, v) {
    data[k][s] = v;
  };

  graphs.get = function(k, v) {
    return data;
  };
}]);
```

From your controller:

```
// Stores the this.fav variable as myFavoriteValue (data.myFavoriteValue)
graphsData.set('myFavoriteValue', this.fav);
```

To get the value simply call the `get` function of the service:

```
graphsData.get().myFavoriteValue;
```